# Why does SHA1 on MySQL computes different hashes with plus operator?

Tags: mysql, hash, operators, sha1, concatenation

When executing a `sha1()` on mysql I get different results depending on how the strings get concatenated.

***Query with plus operator***

```
SELECT SHA1("test"+"6JjSrnm5HX4MiNmJpC0M8VMAj4No6Bv9")
```

results in hash `c1dfd96eea8cc2b62785275bca38ac261256e278`

***Query with `CONCAT()`***

```
SELECT SHA1(CONCAT("test", "6JjSrnm5HX4MiNmJpC0M8VMAj4No6Bv9"))
```

results in hash `17b80b7eb824d0796c6203a231ac2b2d5f41f949`

Why does MySQL behave that like that?

*The query's where executed in PHPMyadmin*

Comment: Just made up this little test: `set @tester = "test"+"6JjSrnm5HX4MiNmJpC0M8VMAj4No6Bv9";
select @tester;` and the result is 6...very different with the result of concat btw....cheers ;)

Comment: I see, thank you :) Just post it as an answer, it has great self learning effect :P Were mixing things up with C#.

Comment: @Kimmax...when i have doubts like this one, i always made one of those simple test, and you can aply them to lots of cases...cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this litlle test:

```
set @tester = "test"+"6JjSrnm5HX4MiNmJpC0M8VMAj4No6Bv9"; 
select @tester;
```

This show the number `6` as result.
This way we can observe the difference with `concat` and why the `sha1` computations where different.